# How to detect the case of string?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a variable containing strings. The strings are either with a capital letter at the start of each word or they are all capital letters. I want to detect the case of the string.

I want to do something like:

```
df <- c()
df$strings <- c("Winston", "WINSTON", "Julia", "O'Brien", "JULIA")
for(i in 1:nrow(df$strings)){
  if(str_case_detect(df$strings[i], "UPPER") == TRUE){
    out[i] <- df$strings[i]
  }
}
```

This would give out as "WINSTON" and "JULIA".

Is this at all possible? I couldn't find anything after searching around.

Comment: You could start with `!grepl( "[a-z]", df$strings)` to find the ones without a lower case letter.

Comment: `df$strings[!grepl("[a-z]", df$strings)]` or `grep("[a-z]", df$strings, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Hint: `toupper("Winston") == "Winston"` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, you've all be really helpful and come up with solutions I would never have thought of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
txt <- c("Winston", "WINSTON", "Julia", "O'Brien", "JULIA")

txt[grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", txt)] # match only all upper case
[1] "WINSTON" "JULIA"  

txt[!grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", txt)] # match not all upper case 
[1] "Winston" "Julia"   "O'Brien"
```